# Invalid docker.compose.yaml file

Tags: docker

I am trying to get a couple of containers up and running, however I am running into some issues. I run this command:

docker-compose up -d --build itvdflab

and get this error

The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'itvdelab'
Unsupported config option for networks: 'itvdelabnw'

Here is the yaml file.

```
 services:
  itvdelab:
    image: itversity/itvdelab
    hostname: itvdelab
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./itversity-material:/home/itversity/itversity-material"
      - "./data:/data"
    environment:
      SHELL: /bin/bash
    networks:
      - itvdelabnw
    depends_on:
      - "cluster_util_db"
  cluster_util_db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "6432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./cluster_util_db_scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - itvdelabnw
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: itversity
  itvdflab:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: images/pythonsql/Dockerfile
    hostname: itvdflab
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./itversity-material:/home/itversity/itversity-material"
      - "./data:/data"
    environment:
      SHELL: /bin/bash
    networks:
      - itvdelabnw
    depends_on:
      - "pg.itversity.com"
  pg.itversity.com:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - itvdelabnw
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: itversity
networks:
  itvdelabnw:
    name: itvdelabnw
```

What changes do I need to make to get this working?

Comment: What version of docker-compose do you use? You can see it by running the command `docker-compose --version`

Comment: docker-compose version 1.17.1

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am trying to set up this environment on AWS Cloud9.

Answer (score 1):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file is missing a `version:` line.  Until very recently, this caused Docker Compose to interpret this as the original "version 1" Compose format, which doesn't have a top-level `services:` key and doesn't support Docker networks.  The much newer Compose Specification claims that a `version:` key is optional, but in practice if you can't be guaranteed to use a very new version of Compose (built as a plugin to the `docker` binary) it's required.  The most recent Compose file versions supported by the standalone Python `docker-compose` tool are 3.8 and 2.4 (you need the 2.x version for some resource-related constraints in non-Swarm installations).

```yaml
# Add at the very beginning
version: '3.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

for me work try different version. In my case work

version: '2.2'